# python set empty string to null in list

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me why my for/if statement at the bottom isn't setting empty strings in the list domaininfo to `None` ?

```
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    domaininfo = line.split(',')

    if line!= '':
        Id = None
        fakedomain = domaininfo[1]
        A = domaininfo[2]
        AAAA = domaininfo[3]
        MX = domaininfo[4]
        NS = domaininfo[5]
        country = domaininfo[6]
        whois_created = domaininfo[7]
        whois_updated = domaininfo[8]
        SSDEEP = domaininfo[9]

        for item in domaininfo[1:]:
            if not item:
                item = None
```

output is:

```
['blah.com', '1.1.1.1', '', 'mx1.somemxserver.com', 'ns2.somensserver.net', 'Spain', '', '', '\n']
```

Desired output:

```
['blah.com', '1.1.1.1', None, 'mx1.somemxserver.com', 'ns2.somensserver.net', 'Spain', None, None, '\n']
```

Comment: actually @ShawnMehan, an empty string will return False, ie `s = ''` >>> `bool(s)` >> `False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting a variable, not a list entry:

```
for i, item in enumerate(domaininfo[1:]):
    if not item:
        domaininfo[i + 1] = None
```